# Arrangement of elements in the jetpack compose row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, row

I need to position the loading circle in the center of the screen, but right now I'm getting like this:

[image: Now it looks like this:]

Circle code:

```
@Composable
fun CircularProgressBar(isLoading: Boolean) {
    if(isLoading) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 10.dp),
            color = Color.Gray
        )
    }
}
```

Row code:

```
Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 15.dp, bottom = 15.dp),
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_24),
                    contentDescription = "back",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(35.dp)
                )
            }

            CircularProgressBar(isLoading = true)
        }
```

I want to achieve what is shown in the following image with the loading indicator in the center:

[image: I need to do this:]

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you couldn't center the indicator because of this arrangement line. `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween`. It affects all the childs in the row in your situation. I suggest you to use `Box` instead of `Row` here is an example.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Yellow)

) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = { /*Do Something*/ },
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .align(Alignment.CenterStart),
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_24),
            contentDescription = "back",
            modifier = Modifier.size(35.dp)
        )
    }

    CircularProgressBar(
        isLoading = true,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .align(Alignment.Center),
    )
}

@Composable
fun CircularProgressBar(isLoading: Boolean, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
   if (isLoading) {
    // Use your indicator here
    Box(modifier = modifier.size(40.dp).background(Color.Red))
 }
}
```

**This is what it looks like**
[image]